# Windbg conditional breakpoint won't break?

Tags: c, debugging, windbg

Using *Windbg*, I'm trying to break conditionally using the following src file: *basic_thread.cpp*:

```c
9:  void __stdcall process()
10: {
11:    unsigned int count = 100000000;
12:    unsigned int hits = 0;
13:    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
14:    {
15:        // Not much to look at.
16:        hits++;
17:    }
18: }
```

My breakpoints are set like so:

```
bu `basic_thread.cpp:12` 
    ".if (poi(count)==0n100000000){.echo 'count==100000000'} .else {gc}"
```

```
bu `basic_thread.cpp:16` 
    ".if (poi(hits)==0n500){.echo 'hits==500'} .else {gc}"
```

After setting them, I restart my program and run, but the breakpoints are never realised?

`.restart`

`g`

What is wrong with my breakpoints?

**Edit**

I've read the official doco [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint), and my breakpoints look accurate, but they still don't break.

Comment: Have you tried putting the breakpoints on different lines? `hits` isn't in scope on line 11, and I'm not sure `count` is at that point either.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. The example should read line 12 and 16... but, it still doesn't break.

Comment: No idea why this would be down-voted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're failing because you are mixing c++ expression with MASM expression.
The MASM engine doesn't understand your `hits` or `counts`.  You must qualify them with `@@c++()` syntax.

I just compiled and ran a simple test to simulate what you want in your question:

```
:\>ls
windbp.cpp

:\>cl /Zi /W4 /Od /analyze /EHsc /nologo windbp.cpp /link /release /nologo
windbp.cpp

:\>cdb -c ".lines;bp `windbp.cpp:16` \".if( @@c++(hits) != 500 ) { gc }\";g" windbp.exe
```

And the result is:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 X86

ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
773005a6 cc              int     3

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.lines;bp `windbp.cpp:16` ".if( @@c++(hits) != 500 ) { gc }";g'
Line number information will be loaded
ModLoad: 6d300000 6d303000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL
eax=00000500 ebx=7ffd6000 ecx=00000500 edx=00000500 esi=009c8648 edi=00349098
eip=0098102e esp=0028f838 ebp=0028f844 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000287
windbp!process+0x2e:
0098102e 8b55f8          mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp-8] ss:0023:0028f83c=00000500
0:000> ?? hits
unsigned int 0x500
0:000>
```

Here is my samples src:

```
0:000> lsa .
     8: //space filler
     9: void __stdcall process()
    10: {
    11:    unsigned int count = 100000000;
    12:    unsigned int hits = 0;
    13:    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    14:    {
    15:        // Not much to look at.
>   16:        hits++;
    17:    }
    18: }
    19:
    20: int main(void) {
    21:     process();
    22:     return 0;
    23: }
0:000>
```